# porting python code(linux) to windows

Tags: python, linux

i wrote a program using python with PyQT4 and other modules like numpy, scipy etc. under Linux(Ubuntu 9.10). Now i want a executable of this program under Windows 7. I dont want to install Python on the Windows 7 OS.

i try pyinstaller, cx_freeze and py2exe under linux, but i generate only a linux executable which works fine under linux but not working under Windows.

Now my Questions are.

1. Is my Task possible or need i to install Python and the needed packages on Windows 7 to generate the executable with pyinstaller for examble?
2. if it is possible--> how is the solution to solve the problem.

regards lars

Answer (score 3):

I only have experience with py2exe and pyqt4, but py2exe needs several dlls which can only exist inside a Windows environment (like Visual C runtime libs or the dlls for Qt). It might be hackable with Wine, but having a Windows environment for packaging everything is the "supported" way.

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller's [Supported Packages page](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/SupportedPackages) lists PyQT4 as supported so I'd give that a try - just get your application running as a conventional Python application under Windows 7, then run PyInstaller as usual.  From personal experience I know it'll handle matplotlib, NumPy and SciPy without a hitch.